# Testing south migrations in Django

Tags: django, django-south

Does anyone know a way to test the *migration itself* after writing it? Very many times in my DataMigrations I've found stupid subtle bugs, like `True` instead of `False` for the default value, wrong denormalizations, etc.

The default South convention is to start the migrations with numbers, so you can't even import them without using `__import__`. Has anyone came up upon a similar problem? How do people solve them?

The most obvious approach would be to hold the migration logic in a separate imported module and test that, but that's somewhat clunky.

Comment: Why not simply write unit tests that test the new schema? e.g., create a model without specifying a value, and check that the correct default is used.

Comment: @Michael: That's ok for schemamigrations, but it won't find a bug in datamigrations.

Comment: In that case, you can create a database for migration testing, populate with sample data, run the migration, and test the final values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled into the same problem. Since I didn't find a way to do tests for datamigrations, I used assertions to detect corrupt data:

```
from django.conf import settings

class MyModel(models.Model):
    stupid_error = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if settings.DEBUG:
            assert not self.stupid_error
```

Ok, it's a bit clunky. But it seems to work.

[Edit]
Thinking about it again, I found a much better solution: put the tests into the DataMigration itself. Since a migration is one-off code, it doesn't have to be tested over and over.

```
class Migration(DataMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        # lots of awesome migration code here
        # ...
        for m in orm.MyModel.objects.all():
            assert not m.stupid_error
```

Comment: Don't know, you're mixing stuff that shouldn't together, tests are one thing and migrations are another....

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to South, but the few times I used it, I used unit tests as well and then, ./`manage.py test` executed the migrations as well, this would already find many bugs.

However, this probably does not work in all cases (I think there is no data in the test database when these migrations are executed).